# Regression - mean squared error

Tags: statistics

For $i=1,2,\dots,n$, let $Y_i = f(x_i) + \epsilon_i$, where $\epsilon_i$ are iid $N(0,\sigma^2)$. Let $f$ be estimated by $\hat{f}$. Let $x_0$ be a new value of $x$ (not any of $x_1,\dots,x_n$), so $Y_0 = f(x_0) + \epsilon_0$; we assume $\epsilon_0 \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ and $\epsilon_0$ is independent of $\epsilon_1, \dots, \epsilon_n$. Show that \begin{equation*}E\left((Y_0-\hat{f}(x_0))^2\right) = \sigma^2 + \text{Var}(\hat{f}(x_0))+\left(\text{Bias}(\hat{f}(x_0))\right)^2\end{equation*}

By rewriting the left-hand side as $E\left(\left((Y_0-f(x_0))+(f(x_0)-\hat{f}(x_0))\right)^2\right)$, expanding, and making some manipulations, I have reduced the problem to showing that $E(\epsilon_0 \hat{f}(x_0)) = 0$. But I cannot figure out how to do that. Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how $\hat{f}$ is estimated? Is it a linear regression, and are the $x$'s real numbers or vectors?

Comment: The $x$s are real numbers. The only other information given about $\hat{f}$ is that it's an estimator for $f$ which depends on $(x_i,y_i)$ for $i=1,2,\dots,n$.

Comment: Thanks. Is $\epsilon_{0}$ not independent of all the other variables in the model? And so:  $E(\epsilon_0 \hat{f}(x_0)) = E(\epsilon_0) E(\hat{f}(x_0)) = 0$. Thus, the answer is immediate from you reduction? Since $\hat{f}$ is estimated without $x_{0}$, then $\hat{f}$ should be independent of $\epsilon_0$ regardless of how it is estimated.

Comment: Yes, I guess that's right, as discussed more fully in K. A. Buhr's answer below. I was trying to apply the formal definition of independence and couldn't see it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We assume here that all the $x_i$ and $f$ are deterministic, and the only source of randomness are the $\epsilon_i$s.  The expression $\hat f(x_0)$ applies a random function to a non-random value $x_0$.  What makes $\hat f$ random?  It is the result of a regression of $Y_i$ on $x_i$ for $i=1,\dots,n$.  The only source of randomness in these observations are the $\epsilon_i, i=1,\dots,n$, so $\hat f$ is a deterministic function of $\epsilon_1,\dots,\epsilon_n$.

Thanks to the independence, of $\epsilon_0$ from $\{\epsilon_1,\dots,\epsilon_n\}$, we have $\epsilon_0$ independent from $\hat f$ and therefore from $\hat f(x_0)$, its application to the non-random value $x_0$.  So, your expectation is the expectation of a product of two indepedent random variables, which can be written as the product of the expectations, one of which is $E(\epsilon_0)=0$.  Therefore, the expectation is zero, as required.